# Building SOAP message with XMLDocument VB.NET

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, soap, xmldocument

I am having some problems building a properly formatted **SOAP** message using **XMLDocument** in VB.NET(C# answers are fine though).

I am using the following code to manually create my **SOAP** message, what is happening is that the namespace prefix of the **soap:Header** and **soap:Body** are being stripped in the output XML:

```
Dim soapEnvelope As XmlElement = _xmlRequest.CreateElement("soap", "Envelope", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
soapEnvelope.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
soapEnvelope.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
_xmlRequest.AppendChild(soapEnvelope)
Dim soapHeader As XmlElement = _xmlRequest.CreateElement("soap", "Header", String.Empty)
_xmlRequest.DocumentElement.AppendChild(soapHeader)
Dim soapBody As XmlElement = _xmlRequest.CreateElement("soap", "Body", String.Empty)
_xmlRequest.DocumentElement.AppendChild(soapBody)
```

This results in the following output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Header>
  ...
 </Header>
 <Body>
  ....
 </Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What I need is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soap:Header>
  ...
 </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
  ....
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**NOTE:** I appreciate all input, but regardless of any references to how **SOAP** should work or be parsed on the receiving side or anything like that, the bottom line is I need to generate the XML as described for. Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION:**
Very similar to **Quartmeister** answer was the way I resolved this. The issue was in fact in relation to namespace. Rather than use the string value every time though, I used the following solution using the **NamespaceURI** of the **DocumentElement**:

```
Dim soapHeader As XmlElement = _xmlRequest.CreateElement("soap", "Header", _xmlRequest.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
Dim soapBody As XmlElement = _xmlRequest.CreateElement("soap", "Body", _xmlRequest.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the XML namespace on the Header and Body elements to the soap namespace:

```
Dim soapHeader As XmlElement = _xmlRequest.CreateElement("soap", "Header", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
Dim soapBody As XmlElement = _xmlRequest.CreateElement("soap", "Body", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
```

Comment: @Quartmeister - +1 Thanks for the response. I actually had just solved the problem using the DocumentElement.NamespaceURI, which is essentially the same as your answer. Give you the answer though since it is correct. Thanks!