# consuming a php web service with asp.net

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, post, web-reference

i wanna consume a php web service with asp.net but web service requires post data. So add reference tab is not working for me? is there any solution to that problem.

thanks

Comment: Do you have any more information on the PHP service?  "Web service" isn't very specific.  What are the requirements to integrate with that service?

Comment: i have a web service than i post an xml to this service it returns me an another xml. soap, and xml-rpc request could be send

Answer (score 1):

If your php service has a WSDL, you can use that to consume the service in .Net, otherwise you need to generate your soap messages manually - see [Building SOAP message with XMLDocument VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294251/building-soap-message-with-xmldocument-vb-net) for an example